# Запятая в предложении: "Поэтому во избежание драм(,) смотрите в оба"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Поэтому во избежание драм(?) смотрите в оба.

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

Answer (score 3):

***Поэтому, во избежание драм, смотрите в оба. - Поэтому во избежание драм смотрите в оба.***

Возможны два варианта пунктуационного оформления данного предложения.

Обычно обстоятельственные обороты с производными предлогами **обособляются, если** находятся не в начале и не в конце предложения, содержат объяснение того, о чём говорится в предложении, выделяются интонационно. В этом предложении я бы запятые поставила.

В спорных случаях окончательное решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста.

Об этом можно прочитать здесь: [Пунктуация при оборотах с непервообразными предлогами](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)

Answer (score 2):

Такие предложения имеют авторское решение, но автор должен видеть те факторы, которые могут влиять на выбор обособленного или необособленного варианта.

Я бы поставила здесь запятые: Поэтому, во избежание драм, смотрите в оба.

Семантический фактор. Здесь важно разделить предложение на две части, выделив причину и  основное содержание предложения.

Фонетический фактор. Предложение без обособления "плохо читается", так как в этом случае мы должны читать слитно "поэтому во избежание", а делать это неудобно и нежелательно.

И приводить для проверки другие предложения тоже нежелательно (я имею в виду пример "лучше для надежности откройте глаза"), там свой смысл и своя фонетика. Также придумывать предложения, оторванные от реального текста, тоже не лучший вариант: каждое предложение должно вписываться в свой контекст.

И вообще, мне кажется, что не любой грамматически связанный набор слов можно назвать предложением, это опять же касается приведенного примера. Его лучше записать так: для надежности лучше откройте глаза. Но опять же надо и этот вариант сверять по контексту.

Answer (score 0):

Без запятой. Это повелительное предложение — простое, неделимое, цельное по смыслу. Переиначим так: "Лучше для надежности откройте глаза".